# Region code folding for javascript

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I was looking for a way to fold my JavaScript code in [Atom](https://atom.io/) using something like C# regions:

```
#region: hey
//some cool code here
#endregion
```

I couldn't find any package like this. I know that you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and fold whatever code is selected. But I want to have named regions.

So the real question is, **does anybody know how can I do this in Atom?**

Thanks!

Comment: _if your question generally covers… **software tools commonly used by programmers** …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!_ -  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: that was a big burn lol

Comment: [`custom-folds`](https://atom.io/packages/custom-folds)

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for the same and I found the package [custom-folds](https://atom.io/packages/custom-folds).

By default, it will fold the code between `// <editor-fold>` and `// </editor-fold>` but you can customize it to work as `// region` and `// endregion` (notice the space between `//` and `region`. The package is in active development so it will soon support `#region`. See the bug https://github.com/bsegraves/custom-folds/issues/3